# MOSTRAR MNS EN JAVASCRIPT CON CSS

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, css, insert

me gustaría saber si me pueden ayudar, el mensaje de el `if (errores.length > 0)` me sale muy bien cuando mando mi mensaje, pero al momento de poner el otro mensaje en el `else` no me sale nada, a lo mejor es un error muy lógico sin embargo no he podido encontrarlo ... Espero me puedan ayudar... Lo que quiero hacer es que en donde aparece registro insertado en mi PHP me lo agregue en el mensaje como en el fragmento de javascript donde me muestra los errores, espero me puedan ayudar

FRAGMENTO CODIGO CSS:

```
/* Ventana de errores*/

.modal_wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 3;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.mensaje_modal {
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    width: 400px;
    padding: 30px 20px 15px;
}

.mensaje_modal h3 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu';
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.mensaje_modal h3:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background: #C5C5C5;
    margin: 10px 0px 15px;
}

.mensaje_modal p {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #606060;
}

.mensaje_modal p:before {
    content: "\f00d";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #E25151;
    margin-right: 8px;
}

#btnClose {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background: #E25151;
    color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #B14141;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
}


/* Ventana de mensaje bien*/

.modal_wrap_a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 3;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.mensaje_modal_a {
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    width: 400px;
    padding: 30px 20px 15px;
}

.mensaje_modal_a h3 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu';
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.mensaje_modal_a h3:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background: #C5C5C5;
    margin: 10px 0px 15px;
}

.mensaje_modal_a p {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #606060;
}

.mensaje_modal_a p:before {
    content: "\f00d";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #E25151;
    margin-right: 8px;
}
```

FRAGMENTO CÓDIGO JAVASCRITP:

```
/* El "== false" sobra en la comprobación */
            if (errores.length > 0) {
                /* Cancelo el envío del formulario */
                e.preventDefault();
                /* Usamos plantillas para ver mejor el código HTML */
                let mensajeModal = `
                <div class="modal_wrap">
                    <div class="mensaje_modal">
                        <h3>Errores encontrados</h3>
                        ${errores}
                        <span id="btnClose">Cerrar</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            `;

                $('body').append(mensajeModal);
            } else {
                let mensajeModal = `
                <div class="modal_wrap_a">
                    <div class="mensaje_modal_a">
                        <h3>OK</h3>
                        
                        <span id="btnClose">Cerrar</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            `;

                $('body').append(mensajeModal);


            }

            // CERRANDO MODAL ==============================
            $('#btnClose').click(function() {
                $('.modal_wrap').remove();
            });
        });
```

FRAGMENTO PHP

```
/* Es mejor usar comparaciones estrictas para comprobar si hubo error */
if ($resultado === false) {
    die('Error en la consulta: '. htmlspecialchars($conn->error));
}
/* En caso de que no hubiera error, devolvermos el mensaje esperado */
die('Registro insertado');
}else {
    echo '<p>Corrige los siguientes errores:<br>'  . implode('<br>', $errores) . '</p>';
}
```

Comment: En tu código Javascript no se ve lo que es la variable `errores`. Por otra parte, parecería que estás trabajando con Ajax. Una forma más organizada de trabajar en ese caso sería creando en el servidor un array y poniendo a ese array una clave error, con un mensaje, algo así: `"error"=>"Mensaje de error"` y devolviendo un JSON al cliente, luego, en Javascript, imaginando que recibes una respuesta en `data`, harías esto: `if (data.error) {  /*Mostrar en el contenedor dedicado a los errores el contenido de data.error*/ } else { /*No hubo error, leer o mostrar data donde sea necesario*/ }`

Comment: Muchas gracias :)